# Get Source for Arch Linux Package?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, source-code

In Debian based distributions you can run `apt-get source <package_name>` to fetch the source code for a package. What is the equivalent for `pacman` on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 8):

1. Install the [Arch Build Source Management Tool](https://github.com/falconindy/asp) (i.e. the `asp` command, formerly `abs`).

   ```
   sudo pacman -S asp
   ```
2. Download the PKGBUILD

   ```
   asp export <package_name>
   ```
3. Download the PKGBUILD source files

   ```
   cd <package_name>
   makepkg -do
   ```

   > **-d, --nodeps**
   >   Do not perform any dependency checks. This will let you override and
   >   ignore any dependencies required. There is a good chance this option
   >   will break the build process if all of the dependencies are not
   >   installed.
   >
   > **-o, --nobuild**
   >   Download and extract files, run the prepare() function, but do not build
   >   them. Useful with the --noextract option if you wish to tweak the files
   >   in $srcdir/ before building.

   You may need to add `--skippgpcheck` if you get this error

   > ==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
4. Source will be be in `src` sub-directory.

---

If you find that you're doing this frequently, you could add a function to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

```
function get-source()
{
    asp export $1 && \
    pushd $1 && \
    makepkg -do --skippgpcheck && \
    pushd src
}
```

Then you can just run

```
get-source <package_name>
```

Comment: It doesn't download the history :c E.g. I stumbled upon a packaging bug *(apparently i3-wm archlinux packagers included some broken patch)*, so I need to bisect it to make sure it's the patch that causes the problem. But `git log` — `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):` ‍♂️

Comment: Oh, I found in docs for `asp`: turns out using `checkout` *(as in `asp checkout i3-wm`)* fixes that. The files will be located under the `repos/` dir.